# How to unlock root partition using LiveUSB Gparted

Tags: linux, fedora, partition, gparted

After hours of searching on the internet for answers, I still cannot unlock my root partition in GParted. I want to add 100gb unallocated space to my current `/dev/nvme0n1p7` "fedora_localhost-live" 33gb partition. I am running dual boot fedora 31 on my Windows 10 device. Does anyone know what I am missing here?

I have done the following:

- Created LiveUSB GParted
- Created 100gb of unallocated space
- Checked if the root partition is mounted.

```
    umount /dev/nvme0n1p7
    umount: /dev/nvme0n1p7: not mounted.
```

Below is my vgdisplay:

```
VG Name               fedora_localhost-live
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <33.18 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              8493
  Alloc PE / Size       8493 / <33.18 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
```

I noticed that I have got no PE size left for my partition, but is does say resizable.

I cannot "deactivate" the partition in Gparted while booted from the LiveUSB, thus I cannot extend the partition. The ext4 partition get's unlocked when I boot from LiveUSB.

I can move the unallocated space two rows down, but the lvm2 partition is unable to extend with the 100gb. Everywhere I read that LiveUSB should deactivate the partition, but it seems that he's still running or there is another problem which I don't see.

[image: Gparted screenshot]

Comment: Which partition are you trying to expand? From your image it looks like you can expand p3 forward into unallocated or you can expand p4 backwards (generally has to move stuff to go backwards into a partition). You can shuffle/slide stuff around but it tends to be slow and painful as it's a ton of copying.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear. I am trying to expand the `/dev/nvme0n1p7` partition.

Comment: p7 doesn't have any free space on either side of it. The free space has to be adjacent to the partition you are trying to expand. Logically partitions are contiguous.

Comment: I can move the unallocated on top of p7, but when I do that I don't get the option to it resize nor move p7

Comment: What do you mean by "Created LiveUSB GParted"? You booted your system from a usb drive?

Comment: Exactly, with on the USB Gparted. Through Linux Method D from this website: https://gparted.org/liveusb.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to move this 100GB space. Just create there partition. Then create this partition PV

```
pvcreate /dev/partition_name
```

then add the PV to the VG

```
vgextend fedora_localhost-live /dev/partition_name
```

And you have 100GB more in your VG

Comment: This did the trick adding 100GB to my VG! When I run `vgdisplay` it is added as Free PE. Maybe a silly question, but do I still need to mount or set the new `/dev/partition_name`? Because I still don't have the 100GB available for my device.

Comment: @DennisLoos, no, you do not need to mount it. You can check with `pvs`, `vgs`commands what is the situation